# string format for amount in indian format in MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, string-formatting

I am developing a MVC app.
I have some amount fields. by default it showing numbers without comma separation. 
for e.g. if I have amount 500000000 then I want to display it like 50,00,00,000 
I want to show in Indian currency format,in indian format first comma comes after 3 digits then for every 2 digits comma appears.

How to do this ?

I have tried this , but giving an error...

```
 @{  

                   long myNumber = 123981202803;
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo Indian = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
                    }
                   @(String.Format(Indian, "{0:N}", modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount))
}
```

Comment: Use this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8117453/1042240

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object[]' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: the error is due to this `modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount`

Comment: ya, but how to display it ? I want to show it in index view.

Comment: you can modify this into your requirement 
`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount, string.Format("sAmount{0}", item.Id),"sAmount")`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29904/discussion-between-user1650894-and-ahmed-z)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the appropriate culture for each region you want specific formatting for.
Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CultureInfo Indian = new CultureInfo("in-IN");
String.Format(Indian,"{0:N}", myNumber);
```

In the view add something like: (list of culutres i.e "hi-IN" [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/))

```
<h3>
    @{  
        long myNumber = 123981202803;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo Indian = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
     }
     @(String.Format(Indian, "{0:N}", myNumber))
</h3>
```

Prodcues

```
1,23,98,12,02,803.00
```

Comment: Thanks HennyH, but I am displaying amount in grid/index view. I have below code , where I have to put the string format ?       `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount)`