# How to set amount column as indian currency format in gridview C#?

Tags: c#, gridview

I attached data source & doing simple calculation in gridview. When i calculate total amount it showing like this **30000**, but i need to show like this **Rs.30,000.00**. how to do this in gridview column ?

Comment: i'd be surprised if you got no results when you searched. You did search first, right?

Comment: oh look! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117417/formatting-decimal-number-to-display-comma-as-a-seprator-but-in-indian-currency

Comment: You should check out (what I assume is a decimal) `.ToString("C")` string format option.

Comment: ya i agree with @siva.k and also use `.ToString("n")` for .00 format